# Javascript Objects, For loop mutlidimensional array to create new object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have bellow array and want to create new one object will take ID + attendees (name/photo)

so the output should be new `object = [{id:1, name: 'tom'}, {id:2, name: 'john'}]`

Need vanilla JS prefer es6

```
const eventData = [{
    id: "1",
    title: 'event1'
    attendees: [{
      name: "Tom",
      photoURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/22.jpg"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: 'event2'
    attendees: [{
      name: "John",
      photoURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/22.jpg"
    }]
  }
];
```

And want to create a new object with the format to be like this

```
const attendees = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "Tom",
    photoURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/22.jpg"

  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Tom",
    photoURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/22.jpg"
  }
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"Need vanilla JS prefer es6"* have you at least tried by yourself, or are just demanding us to code it for you? If you tried, please share the code with us, then we can guide toward a solution

Comment: This looks like a good use case for the array "map" function. Ie, `eventData.map()`, especially if the `attendees` array is always a single entry...

Comment: Something like `eventData.reduceRight((acc, v) => v.attendees.map(at => ({ ...at, id: v.id })).concat(acc),  [])`?

Answer (score 1):

### I think this is your answer

```js
function alex() {
  let objects = [
    { id: 1, name: "tom" },
    { id: 2, name: "john" }
  ];

  const eventData = [
    {
      id: "1",
      title: "event1",
      attendees: [
        {
          name: "Tom",
          photoURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/22.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      title: "event2",
      attendees: [
        {
          name: "John",
          photoURL: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/22.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  eventData.map(eventDataObject => {
    let findById = objects.findIndex(
      x => Number(x.id) === Number(eventDataObject.id)
    );
  let findByName = objects.findIndex(
      x => x.name === eventDataObject.attendees[0].name)
   
    let objectsCopy = [...objects];
    objectsCopy[findById].image = eventDataObject.attendees[0].photoURL;
    objects = objectsCopy;
  });

  console.log("objects:",objects);
}
alex();
```

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for everyone try to help, and thanks for everyone give negative feedback (i am still starter - please be patient with newbies questions)

**Here is my solution (maps + es6 object destructions)**

```
const eventData = [
  {
    id: "1",
    attendees: 
      {
        name: "Bob",
        age: 30
      }

  },
  {
    id: "2",
    attendees: 
      {
        name: "kareem",
        age: 22
      },

  }
];




const newList = eventData.map(entry => {
  const id = entry.id;
  const attendees = entry.attendees;
  let newObjs = {id,...attendees};
})

newList.map(entry => console.log(entry))
```

output:

```
> Object { id: "1", name: "Bob", age: 30 }
> Object { id: "2", name: "kareem", age: 22 }
```

Comment: ***This does not answer the question that was asked.*** : In the original question, the `attendees` property is an **`Array`** of objects. In this answer, the source data has been modified and the `attendees` property is now a single object. There is no-longer a "multidimensional" aspect to the source data.

Comment: The code provided does not show the output that you have quoted. Actual output is `undefined`, `undefined`.